# how to change system font size in Windows WITHOUT rescaling websites in browsers?

Tags: windows-11

I've been searching high and low for a solution but found none.

I changed the size of system font in windows 11 (settings->accessibility->text size) to make it more legible in app titlebars etc. (working often in Ubuntu 22 and got used to larger font size).

However when setting system font size to say 120% the website I'm developing is also zoomed in/rescaled with all images and fonts. I've tried css base sizes, browser settings - no result. Everything is zoomed in. I could actually ctrl + - in the browser but then I don't know what is the actual 100% size with users, besides images/logos look blurry.

As in the title - is that even possible in Windows to change system font size in Windows WITHOUT rescaling websites in browsers?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: In Firefox you can override the fonts (including size) **and** the zoom level.

Comment: There are plenty of websites that will show you how your site appears on a variety of operating systems and websites

Comment: @DavidPostill Firefox and Chrome - the same problem. I know can manually manipulate zoom or force browser fonts over website ones but it shouldn't work like that - changing system font size should not interfere with website contents displayed in browsers... thanks for your efforts to help! :)

Comment: Most Windows programs respect the fonts and zoom defined by the operating system. Why do you think browsers should behave any differently - especially since you can configure them to not do so? You could raise a feature request if you really need this functionality

Comment: @DavidPostill on the one hand you're right BUT here we're talking ONLY about font size NOT zoom; system font size should not influence physical dimensions of displayed images on websites (web developer tools still show nominal 500px as width but it occupies 600px on the screen. Everything is upscaled. To me it's weird. Probably need to stick to Ubuntu only:) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's possible to change the system fonts selectively,
meaning title-bars, menus etc.
This would perhaps not affect the way that the browser displays
content.

For simplicity, you could use the free
[System Font Size Changer](https://www.wintools.info/index.php/system-font-size-changer).
Undo your own system font change before using this tool.

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks - I haven't come across this app as yet. After tests - it changes a lot of elements but the titlebars in Chrome or Firefox stay intact :( Windows 11.